# why is it printing only the last letter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i am wanting to make it so it gets the input from the user and changes it but its only changing the last letter

i have many times to correct this but it doesn't work for some reason

```
from tkinter import *
import random

window = Tk()
window.title("Enigma Ui")
lbl = Label(window, text='''Welcome



''',font=("Comic Sans", 16))
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
window.geometry('350x200')
def clicked():
    res = "" + txt.get()
    keyword5 = ["a"]
    if any(keyword in res for keyword in keyword5):
        lbl.configure(text= "h")
    keyword6 = ["b"]
    if any(keyword in res for keyword in keyword6):
        lbl.configure(text= "j")


btn = Button(window, text="Encrypt", bg="light blue", command = clicked)
btn.grid(column=20, row=30)
txt =Entry(window,width=10)
txt.grid(column=14,row=30)


window.mainloop()
```

i want it to take user input and change all letters not just one

Comment: Can you give your expected output for a particular input? e.g. what output would you expect if the user enters "banana"?

Comment: well im working on that but im expecting that when you enter ab into the interface you will get "hj out

Comment: Also, when asking questions try to make your title more specific, e.g. something like "How to change (or replace) letters in a string in a Tkinter GUI" - then other users with the same question will find your answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your clicked function, when you call lbl.configure() you will always return just the single letter h or j.

Here's a possible different clicked function:

```
def clicked():
    res = "" + txt.get()
    # define a dictionary to match keywords to their encrypted letter
    keywords = {'a': 'h',
                'b': 'j'}

    new_label_value = res
    # use the string replace function to encrypt matching letters in a loop
    for keyword, encrypted in keywords.items():
        new_label_value = new_label_value.replace(keyword, encrypted)
    lbl.configure(text=new_label_value)
```

This will overwrite the keyword letters in a loop and return a new string.

Comment: Thank you very much i have been stuck for 2hrs your a life saver

Comment: Have a look at the replace method under https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods if you haven't seen it before